# How to set variables used in tasks?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to set a variable to contain e.g. the path to a toolchain, that could be used in serveral tasks on a per project basis.

Does VSCode support this?

In my search for a solution the only answer i could find is to use environment variables. But i would like to be able to set this separately for each project/workspace e.g. in the c_cpp_properties.json file.